# select rows with same id but different value in other column and specify column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
|Product|Warehouse|
+-------+------+
|1      |A     |
+-------+------+
|2      |A     |
+-------+------+
|3      |A     |
+-------+------+
|1      |B     |
+-------+------+
|2      |B     |
+-------+------+
```

I would like to select the Product that occurs more than once with the different Warehouse.

The output should be something like:

```
+------+------+
|Product|Warehouse|
+-------+------+
|1      |A     |
+-------+------+
|1      |B     |
+-------+------+
|2      |A     |
+-------+------+
|2      |B     |
+-------+------+
```

This gets me part way there:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Warehouse IN (
    SELECT Warehouse
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Warehouse
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

But I would also like to specify a set of values for Warehouse. So what I want to do is see products that exist in multiple warehouses, but I want to be able to specify which warehouses I want to see.

I will be using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: You should edit your post to include some sample data and the final desired result as it's not really clear what you mean.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

http://rextester.com/LQZJ62189

```
drop table if exists your_table;

create table your_table ( product  int, warehouse varchar(1));

insert into your_table values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'A'),
(1, 'B'),
(2, 'B');

select * from your_table
where product in (
    SELECT product
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY product
    HAVING count(warehouse) > 1)
    order by product;
```

Comment: The question is tagged as Oracle, your solution is MYSQL despite the fact that syntax is almost the same as both follows ANSI. However, Oracle does not have `if exists' command with the drop or create table syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the subquery to a JOIN clause, you could do this:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM your_table T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Warehouse
              FROM your_table2
          GROUP BY Warehouse
            HAVING COUNT(Product) > 1) T2
        ON T1.Warehouse = T2.Warehouse;
```

http://rextester.com/SRL27676

Comment: I like this solution, however, the Warehouse only exists on one table, not both. The only thing that ties the tables together is the product ID. Any suggestions knowing that additional information?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.product,b.wharhouse from 
(select * from warhose) a,
(select * from warhose) b
where a.product=b.product
and a.wharhouse <> b.wharhouse
order by a.product,a.wharhouse desc
```

I join the table with itself for same product and diffrent wharhouse,the result will be all products where exist in more than one wharhouse. this code is correct if there are no duplicate in this table for product and wharhouse .

Comment: you also can write : select a.product,b.wharhouse instead of a.product,b.wharhouse

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: I join the table with itself for same product and diffrent wharhouse,the result will be all products where exist in more than one wharhouse.
this code is correct if there are no duplicate in this table for product and wharhouse .

Comment: Please add this into the post itself rather than in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your own attempt is pretty close, but it shows warehouses with more than one product instead of the other way round.

Therefore:

```
SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE Product IN (
     SELECT Product
        FROM YourTable
        GROUP BY Product
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   )
```